# SQL Parse and retrieve value

Tags: sql, parsing

I have recently had a database table change which has grouped three table values in one column. The new column holds the 3 values and delimits them with ~

(Eg. Col Name: OL_From Value: 2~7548~186)

My old query was using the second value as an index for a left join but now I need to parse out the value and serve it up for as a value for the left join.

The old query looked like

left join run r2 on sr.from_run_id = r2.run_id

However now the "from_run_id" field no longer exists as it is the second value of the above example (Eg. 2~**7548**~186)

splitting the string up with string_split seems easy enough but how do I then retrieve my second value and serve it back to the join.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: well you shouldn't group the 3 values on the same column.

Comment: Ha ha tell me about it, I protested this but unfortunately nothing can be done about it.

Comment: well you can show them this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle?

Comment: Thanks Juan, I'm using sql server. The solution I came up with was (SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(sr.OL_To, '~', '.'), 1))

Answer (score 0):

just create a function to encapsulate the parsing and do

```
 ON getIdFromField(sr.from_run_id) = r2.run_id
```

For example in postgresql you can use `regexp_split_to_array`

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/SZEO46192)**

```
WITH start_string as (
    SELECT '2~7548~186'::text as value

)   
select a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]
from (
    select regexp_split_to_array(value, '~')
    FROM start_string
) as dt(a)
```

and return `a[2]`.

**OUTPUT**

[image]